# Function stored in object does not run when called

Tags: node.js, function, discord.js

I have a main code file called index.js which maps user commands to functions stored in other code files in a subfolder called `/commands`. One of these is match.js which deals with the command "!match". The function for the !match command is exported in an object and called in index.js, however I've not been able to get this to work.

I am following [this](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/dynamic-commands.html#how-it-works) tutorial on dynamic command handling.

I have tried storing the `execute()` function in a few different ways:

```
module.exports = {
    ...,
    execute(message, args) {
        ...
    },
}
```

and

```
module.exports = {
    ...,
    execute: function execute(message, args) {
        ...
    },
}
```

and

```
module.exports = {
    ...,
    execute: function(message, args) {
        ...
    },
}
```

I have this code which handles incoming user commands in index.js.

```
...

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require('./commands/' + file);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

...

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith('!') || message.author.bot) return;

    // Remove ! and split into args
    const args = message.content.slice(1).split(/ +/);
    // Get main command and remove from start of args
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    // If command not found, exit
    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        console.log("Command: " + command);
        console.log(client.commands.get(command));
        console.log("Name: " + client.commands.get(command).name);
        console.log("Description: " + client.commands.get(command).description);
        client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        message.reply('Error in executing command.');
    }
    return;
});
```

And here is the contents of match.js (This code used to reside in index.js and worked without errors)

```
const sheet = require('./../sheet');

module.exports = {
    name: 'match',
    description: 'Returns next match.',
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    execute: function(message, args) {
        console.log('executing match.js');
        sheet()
            .then(
                result => {
                    message.reply(
                        '\n' +
                        'Teams: ' + result[0].home + ' vs ' + result[0].away + '\n' +
                        'Time: ' + result[0].date + ' ' + result[0].time + '\n' +
                        'Competition: ' + result[0].competition + '\n' +
                        'Channel: ' + result[0].channel
                    );
                },
                err => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
    },
};
```

The debugging statements starting with console.log in index.js cause the following output:

```
Command: match
{ name: 'match',
  description: 'Returns next match.',
  execute: [Function: execute] }
Name: match
Description: Returns next match.
```

So the input is being mapped to the correct command object which contains an `execute` function. However when execute is called in the next line, nothing happens. There are no error messages and the console.log statement inside match.js isn't called.

Comment: To be extra sure, what happens if you replace the definition of execute by `execute: 'test'`in match.js?

Comment: Weirdly enough I get the exact same output...    `Command: match
{ name: 'match',
  description: 'Returns next match.',
  execute: [Function: execute] }
Name: match
Description: Returns next match.`    Is it using an older version of match.js for some reason?

Comment: I suspected that it wasn't the object you expected. But I can't really say more with the code you've provided. Maybe another file is matching the command, or maybe this is a build or a dynamic import issue (is this plain node or is it going through webpack or something?). Can you provide more info?

Comment: I eventually solved the problem by re-writing the whole project file by file and line by line in a new directory. I think there must have been some issue with caching exported modules but I don't know if this was to do with node or my own file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by re-writing the whole project file by file and line by line in a new directory. I think there must have been some issue with caching exported modules but I don't know if this was to do with node or my own file system.